# cannot connect to database test1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can connect to mysql, but I get an error saying `Could not select db`.
Is there anything I am missing? Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php 

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','',''); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connection OK'; 

$selected=mysql_select_db("test1",$link) or die("<br>Could q not select db");
mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

Comment: first of all use MySQLi, second post the error message you get, not the or die one you predefined, the one MySQL gives you.

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple factors preventing you from selecting your MySQL database. The following could be the cause:

1. Your connecting to the wrong database server. In this case you are using **localhost**.
2. Your connecting using the wrong username. In this case you are using **no username**
3. Your connecting using the wrong password. In this case you are using **no password**.
4. Your trying to select a database that really does not exist. In this case your trying to select **test1**. If the database does not exist you will need to [create it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html).

You can duplicate what your program is doing by logging onto your console and issuing the following command:

```
mysql -e "show databases"
```

This will list all of the databases available to that user.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
  "<br>Could q not select db"
```

with

```
 "<br>Could q not select db" . mysql_error();
```

to show detailed mysql error.

Mostly you entered the wrong mysql details. Check if the database exist.